# OpenGL 1.4. The scene shifts when I change the center of rotation using mouse picking

Tags: c, opengl

I use the following code to draw the scene, but when the center of rotation changes, the objects on the scene shift down (displacing the scene along the axes), please help find out how to avoid this effect.

```
glTranslated(m_rotationCenter.x, 0, 0);
glTranslated(0, m_rotationCenter.y, 0);
glTranslated(0, 0, m_rotationCenter.z);
glScalef( scale, scale, scale );
glTranslated(-m_rotationCenter.x, 0, 0);
glTranslated(0, -m_rotationCenter.y, 0);
glTranslated(0, 0, -m_rotationCenter.z);
glTranslated(m_rotationCenter.x-xTrans, 0, 0);
glTranslated(0, m_rotationCenter.y+yTrans, 0);
glTranslated(0, 0, m_rotationCenter.z+zTrans);
glRotated( xRot, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
glRotated( yRot, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
glRotated( zRot, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
glTranslated(-m_rotationCenter.x+xTrans, 0, 0);
glTranslated(0, -m_rotationCenter.y-yTrans, 0);
glTranslated(0, 0, -m_rotationCenter.z-zTrans);
glTranslated( -xTrans, 0.0, 0.0 );
glTranslated( 0.0, yTrans, 0.0 );
glTranslated( 0.0, 0.0, zTrans);
```

The center of rotation is changed using mouse picking.

For example, in original center

[image]

Then i change center by mouse click
[image]

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this code:

> ```
> glTranslated(m_rotationCenter.x, 0, 0);
> glTranslated(0, m_rotationCenter.y, 0);
> glTranslated(0, 0, m_rotationCenter.z);
> glScalef( scale, scale, scale );
> glTranslated(-m_rotationCenter.x, 0, 0);
> glTranslated(0, -m_rotationCenter.y, 0);
> glTranslated(0, 0, -m_rotationCenter.z);
> glTranslated(m_rotationCenter.x-xTrans, 0, 0);
> glTranslated(0, m_rotationCenter.y+yTrans, 0);
> glTranslated(0, 0, m_rotationCenter.z+zTrans);
> glRotated( xRot, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
> glRotated( yRot, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
> glRotated( zRot, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
> glTranslated(-m_rotationCenter.x+xTrans, 0, 0);
> glTranslated(0, -m_rotationCenter.y-yTrans, 0);
> glTranslated(0, 0, -m_rotationCenter.z-zTrans);
> glTranslated( -xTrans, 0.0, 0.0 );
> glTranslated( 0.0, yTrans, 0.0 );
> glTranslated( 0.0, 0.0, zTrans);
> ```

Can be written like this and will do exactly the same:

```cpp
glTranslated(m_rotationCenter.x, m_rotationCenter.y, m_rotationCenter.z);
glScalef( scale, scale, scale );
glTranslated(-xTrans, yTrans, zTrans);
glRotated( xRot, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
glRotated( yRot, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
glRotated( zRot, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
glTranslated(-m_rotationCenter.x, -m_rotationCenter.y, -m_rotationCenter.z);
```

But if you want to do a rotation around a point (`m_rotationCenter`), then you have to change the order of the instructions.

Note, to rotate around a pivot, you have to translate the object in that way, that the point of rotation is at the origin (0, 0, 0):

```cpp
glTranslated(-m_rotationCenter.x, -m_rotationCenter.y, -m_rotationCenter.z);
```

The rotate the object:

```cpp
glRotated( xRot, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
glRotated( yRot, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
glRotated( zRot, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
```

Finally move the rotated object back on its original place:

```cpp
glTranslated(m_rotationCenter.x, m_rotationCenter.y, m_rotationCenter.z);
```

Of course this instructions have to be done in the reverse order, because operations like [`glTranslated`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTranslate.xml) and [`glRotated`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRotate.xml) define a new matrix and multiply it to the current matrix.

The final code has to be:

```cpp
glScalef( scale, scale, scale );
glTranslated(-xTrans, yTrans, zTrans);

glTranslated(m_rotationCenter.x, m_rotationCenter.y, m_rotationCenter.z);

glRotated( xRot, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
glRotated( yRot, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
glRotated( zRot, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

glTranslated(-m_rotationCenter.x, -m_rotationCenter.y, -m_rotationCenter.z);
```

---

Further I recommend to do the scaling first (last in the code), so it is easier to define the coordinates like `m_rotationCenter` and `xTrans`, because the scale is not applied to this coordinates.It is applied to the model only:

```cpp
// move the model to its location
glTranslated(-xTrans, yTrans, zTrans);

// rotate the model around `m_rotationCenter`
glTranslated(m_rotationCenter.x, m_rotationCenter.y, m_rotationCenter.z);
glRotated( xRot, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
glRotated( yRot, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
glRotated( zRot, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
glTranslated(-m_rotationCenter.x, -m_rotationCenter.y, -m_rotationCenter.z);

// scale the model
glScalef( scale, scale, scale );
```

Comment: please tell me how to prevent a shift?

Comment: @VictorC See the last part of the answer.